# Как посмотреть список процессов из терминала в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть список процессов из терминала в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

С помощью команды ps.

```
alpha@beta:~$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.1   2808  1644 ?        Ss   14:06   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:06   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:06   0:00 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:06   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:06   0:00 [watchdog/0]
```

Answer (score 12):

Если нужно просто посмотреть, что нагружает процессор или съедает оперативную память, то достаточно будет команды:

```
$ top
```

Answer (score 10):

Есть ещё команд `pstree` -- она отображает процессы в виде дерева.

Answer (score 10):

А еще есть htop, красиво отображает тоже.

Для установки:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: htop сам по себе кушает не мало :)

Answer (score 3):

Мне нравится работать с  atop, очень информативно и удобно

Для установки:

```
sudo apt-get install atop
```