# Как получить список процессов запущенных пользователем с фильтром по имени?

Tags: linux, bash, процесс

Как вывести на экран список процессов, запущенных пользователями, имена которых начинаются с определенного символа (либо строки)? Например, с символа «a»?

Answer (score 3):

Отличной командой для получения именно идентификаторов процессов (PID) по имени является команда [pgrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep).

Команду можно использовать как для получения всех процессов запущенных на данной ОС, так и для отдельного пользователя (параметр `-u`). Пример использования:

```
pgrep -u user_id искомая_строка
```

При необходимости поиска без учета регистра, укажите `-i` перед искомым именем.

Основное применения, в моем случае – для составления скриптов, в которых необходимо совершить действия с группой процессов. Пример ниже показывает как можно экстренно завершить работу браузера Chrome, в случае его зависания

```
pgrep -i chrome | xargs kill -9
```

Похожий вопрос вопрос: [Как посмотреть список процессов из терминала в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/77/)

Comment: Вот, правильный ответ!

Comment: Про pgrep всё верно, вот только вопрос был у автора про начальную букву в имени пользователя, с этим ему что делать? Из ответа непонятно :)

Comment: @approximatenumber Действительно. Видимо не так прочитал, после прочтение ответа. Поскольку вопрос переписан, думаю, стоит задать новый и дать автору этого ссылку на него.

Answer (score 2):

Предположение о ps верное.
Правило первое всегда читать man.
Оттуда можно почерпнуть необходимые опции.

```
sudo ps -ef
```

Покажет все процессы всех пользователей в полном формате.
Дальше нужно просто отфильтровать тех что начинаются с буквы 'a'

```
sudo ps -ef | grep '^a.*'
```

Все.

Comment: не позорьтесь, пожалуйста. уберите вызов программы sudo.